# Function for downloading and reading xml file from web stopped working suddenly

Tags: c#, xml

I've used this exact code (below) for many years and with existing ISP. I just checked to see if it worked - and it no longer allows me to download the xml file.  I get several exceptions when trying to get the Stream object (as shown below).  If I put the same URL into the web browser, provide the same credentials, it works fine to download the xml file. So I am not sure why it won't work in this code anymore. Nothing has changed in the code or in credentials, or xml file. The username and password have not changed. I even tried using the domain name in the credentials in the code (although is not required in web browser).

> Below code for passing credentials if asked for
>   Create a resolver with the necessary credentials.

```
XmlUrlResolver resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
//try username with and without domain name     
// NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("userxyz@mydomain.com", "password1234");
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("userxyz", "password1234");
resolver.Credentials = nc;
// Get a Stream object containing the XML file.
Uri updateXmlUrl = new Uri(UpdateCheckXmlFileUrl);
Stream Updatestream = (Stream)resolver.GetEntity(updateXmlUrl, null, typeof(Stream));
// Construct a reader using the Stream object.
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Updatestream);
```

> Exception error getting stream object
>   [image]

I even tried using new credentials, that perhaps the old ones expire.

Still using .net 4.5 (Visual Studio 2010)

[Watch list on next line below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUxvY.png)

The remaining part of the code is to parse the file read.

//then it suppose to read the XML code from the reader below

```
             reader.MoveToContent();
            string elementName = "";
            Version newVer = null;
            string url = "";
            string msiUrl = "";
            if (StopWorkerThread()) return;

            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "appinfo"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) elementName = reader.Name;
                    else
                    {
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue))
                        {

                            switch (elementName)
                            {
                                case "version":
                                    newVer = new Version(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case "url":
                                    url = reader.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "installer":
                                    msiUrl = reader.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "date":
                                    //elementName = elementName;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // it gets to here and falls through to a false on the versioninfo.Error
            reader.Close();

            versionInfo.Error = false;
            versionInfo.LatestVersion = newVer;
            versionInfo.HomeUrl = url;
            versionInfo.InstallerUrl = msiUrl;
```

Comment: The exceptions in the screen shot may not be the important ones. Those are generated when the debugger attempts to read all properties of the object. But, you can see that the object is in fact created (and your instruction pointer has moved to the next line). What is the error you get when you try to execute the next line, `new XmlTextReader`?

Comment: So the idea of this code is to check the current version number of the software I am running in the application from the xml file on the website. If it can't get the xml file, then it falls through to close.

Comment: I still have no idea what the error message is, or what line it occurs on. How can anyone help without this information?!?! We aren't magicians.

Comment: I am pretty sure the problem is in the Stream Updatestream line, where the exception errors occur.  If this does not resolve properly, everything thereafter will not work, i.e., the XmlTextReader gets its data from the Updatestream.  The problem is I can't seem to drill down on the Stream Updatestream to see why these expections occur.

Comment: I just don't have the information to help you. Imagine how you would advise someone else to proceed with only the information here...

Comment: I am looking for a way to diagnose the problem, not to solve it. If I knew that, I would not be seeking assistance.  I am open to how I can get the information needed. Perhaps, the ISP is blocking this, but again I don't even know where to troubleshoot.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the web request and response. Until you tell us  some error and more detail I can't see how we can help you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip on such a tool.  This gives some place to start. In my prior comment, I meant I need to figure out first how to troubleshoot, then I can solve the problem (hopefully by myself).

Comment: Can you not step through the code one line at a time? Can you make the code perform another request that works and see how that is different?

Comment: While I can step through each line, it is at the line the statement containing resolver.GetEntity () is I believe the issue,  where it returns without the stream to read and exception errors (as shown). I can't drill down into this class using F11. So I can only see what is shown in the watch after it executes.   All the code after that does not matter since the xml file it is trying to access is not there. I am not sure if it is the problem is at the hosting site (although I can read the xml file from a web browser using the same credentials).

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I switched to a different hosting site, and the function works correctly. There seems to be some new security imposed on the original hosting site that kept this from reading the xml file. Odd thing is that I could download using http with a web browser, but not with this function.  On the new hosting site, both work.